# How to work around this in/out mysql parameter bug in Kettle?

Tags: pentaho, kettle

I'm using Kettle for a transformation and hitting this same issue trying to get a value for an integer based 'out' parameter in mysql, (the field should actually be `bigint` but I don't think it's supported in Kettle).

[How to retrieve OUT parameter from MYSQL stored procedure to stream in Pentaho Data Integration (Kettle)?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/23444099/how-to-retrieve-out-parameter-from-mysql-stored-procedure-to-stream-in-pentaho-d)

I've implemented the workaround for this exact issue with decimal but I'm having a hell of a time trying to get the value firstly back into the id field (not `id_1`), and secondly to convert it back to an integer so it can be inserted into the database.

This is the relevant flow:

[image]

This is the step definition:

[image]

On the inbound stream coming out of `lookup existing id` there is already a field added called `id` which is a decimal that may be either a value, or null. If it's null it triggers this db procedure lookup at the `filter rows` step, so in other words, it will always be null at the `db procedure` step (and hence I can't use an in-out parameter here).

So what I want to happen is when it leaves the `db procedure` step, `id` should be populated with the value of the out parameter (ideally it would be an integer, but I can live with decimal because of the bug). But instead I get `id_1` inserted into the stream.

Then further down the line, assuming I have the value in id field as a decimal, I then need to convert that back to an Integer so it can be inserted into the database without error. I don't really know how to write the javascript in Kettle though and I can't find the documentation on the language.

So my questions are twofold:

1. Can I make the db procedure insert `id` back into the stream?
2. How would I write a script(or use a step) that transforms the `id` (or `id_1`) into an Integer and places it back into the `id` field in the stream?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Kettle build on Java and use JDBC driver. Let me summarize some sources and investigate issue ( I will include Postgresql, since i use it most and this information valuable for me)

- http://wiki.pentaho.com/display/EAI/PDI+Rows+Of+Data
- https://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/java/nutsandbolts/datatypes.html
- http://www.tutorialspoint.com/jdbc/jdbc-data-types.htm

First let's check size of data types:  java.util.Long is 8 byte long, mysql bigint type is 8 byte long, postgresql bigint type as well 8 byte long. And by physical size they actually match except one problem. Mysql support unsigned bigint, which is out of scope java.util.Long. I assume problem appears on edge values, min and max value of java.util.Long.

Anyway i tried to reproduce (on Postgres only available at this moment to me)

Postgresql 9.4, JDBC Driver postgresql-9.4-1201-jdbc41.jar, Kettle 5.4.0, jdk7

http://forums.pentaho.com/showthread.php?48950-loosing-precision-of-BIGINT-workaround

and everything looks good. Most probably it is problem with mysql jdbc driver or it is a problem with kettle which doesn't support java.math.BigInteger.  java.math.BigInteger is data type, used to work with unsigned bigint values in mysql as described in here

http://dev.mysql.com/doc/connector-j/en/connector-j-reference-type-conversions.html

About actual problem. Example of solution in here below:
[image]

Sample csv

```
"id" "surname"  "name"  "birth_dt"
"1" "Gorovits"  "Alex"  "2001-01-01"
"2" "Osmani"    "Adeb"  "1998-03-06"
""  "Maiters"   "John"  "1981-07-07"
""  "Mateus"    "Angela"    "2004-04-04"
"5" "Sander"    "Tom"   "1990-05-05"
```

Notes:

- DBLookup doesn't work on null values so u might need to filter rows with null values before to run DBLookup.

Comment: ok thanks, I already had this working actually, I found a "setField" step to take the value out of id_1 and assign it back to id in the db procedure branch. Then I don't know how, but I got the Integer working as well, so maybe some other problem was causing the exception before. But now it's working anyway, and I took out the Javascript step completely.